# Java Charset.forName("ASCII") or Charset.forName("US-ASCII")

Tags: java, character-encoding

I was going through a code and came across the following line.

```
Charset.forName("ASCII")
```

But when I looked at the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) it only has

```
US-ASCII    ISO-8859-1    UTF-8   UTF-16BE   UTF-16LE   UTF-16
```

But the code works. Are 'ASCII' and 'US-ASCII' are synonyms in this context ? or is the code taking some default value since the 'ASCII' is not recognized ? 
And how many bytes does 'ASCII' in this scenario represents a character ?

Comment: Tip: Use enum [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) in Java 7+.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation points out:

> Every charset has a canonical name and may also have one or more
>   aliases. The canonical name is returned by the name method of this
>   class. Canonical names are, by convention, usually in upper case. The
>   aliases of a charset are returned by the aliases method.

Further, the javadoc of `Charset.forName(String charsetName)` tells you:

> charsetName - The name of the requested charset; may be either a
>   canonical name or an **alias**

With this code you can find out more about the charsets:

```
Charset ascii = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
System.out.println(ascii.aliases());
// [ANSI_X3.4-1968, cp367, csASCII, iso-ir-6, ASCII, iso_646.irv:1983, ANSI_X3.4-1986, ascii7, default, ISO_646.irv:1991, ISO646-US, IBM367, 646, us]

System.out.println(ascii.newEncoder().maxBytesPerChar());
// 1.0

Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
System.out.println(utf8.newEncoder().maxBytesPerChar());
// 3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

ASCII is a alias for US-ASCII. It uses a 7-bit byte for each character.

Note: if you want compactness and simplicity, I suggest using ISO-8859-1.  This also uses 1 byte per character but has a wider range. It supports `\u0000` to `u00FF` whereas US-ASCII supports `\u0000` to `\u007F`

Comment: Thanks, it seems IANA prefers the name 'US-ASCII'

Comment: You shouldn't recommending ISO-8859-1 for anything else than compatibility with legacy software. It causes more problems than it solves, and if you don't live in the West (and OP doesn't), it's actually totally useless.

Comment: @KarolS I am pretty sure that encrypted data will produce the same bytes in every country. ;) I stated that using ISO-8859-1 is a bad idea, but it would work, regardless of which language or alphabet because encryption works the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following snippet, prints all charactersets that are available:

```
    SortedMap<String,Charset> availableCharsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
    Set<String> keySet = availableCharsets.keySet();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

I do not see ASCII in the list. Looking at the code for `defaultCharset()` in Charset class shows that if the `file.encoding` is an invalid one, it defaults to 'utf-8'.

Running the following snippet, prints 'UTF-8' as the default charset.

```
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "ASCII");
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: my code seems to work with 'ASCII' where the receiver is expecting 'ASCII'. Therefore if it indeed is invalid and use 'utf-8' then my receiver shouldnt be able to decode it, should it ? First I have to find out whether it indeed use 'ASCII' or switch back to default 'utf-8' as you mentioned. Then i will accept the answer.. Thanks again

Comment: "ASCII" is valid, it's just an alias. See answer by Mathias Begert.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. Java doesn't overwrite the file.encoding when set within the program it seems. When I give a VM argument, ASCII prints `US-ASCII` as the charset name. Thanks.